# Where is the Glacial Crevice?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

The [UESP Wiki](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Touching_the_Sky) states that the fifth way point is `The fifth and final wayshrine, the Wayshrine of Radiance, can only be reached after a long, arduous trek through Forgotten Vale and Glacial Crevice.`

My position's direction and the map marker directions are conflicting. I am waiting at the 4th wayshrine as of now. Clairvoyance has been no help.

How do I reach the Glacial Crevice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the 4th shrine go to the opposite direction from the icy lake. You should see a bridge crossing a stream. Continue to the left of the bridge going down by the stream. At the end of the stream you should find Glacial Crevice.

Here's a Youtube video of the path. The path you're looking for starts around 5:15 on the video.